# capturar el foco en un textfield con teclado personalizado en Swift

Tags: swift

soy nuevo en Swift y estoy tratando de hacer que un teclado personalizado pueda escribir en cualquier text Field al seleccionar este, el problema es que me escribe en uno y al cambiar de textfield sigue escribiendo en otro que ya no tiene el foco, espero me puedan ayudar.

de ante mano muchas gracias abajo dejo el código [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```swift
import UIKit

class triangle: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   var Number = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var cateto1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cateto2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var hipotenuza: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var grados: UITextField!


    @IBAction func number1(_ sender: UITextField) {
        Number = 1
        cateto1.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func number2(_ sender: UITextField) {
        Number = 2
        cateto2.becomeFirstResponder()


    @IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let digit = sender.title(for: .normal)!

        if Number == 1        {
            cateto1.text = cateto1.text! + digit
        }
        else if Number == 2    {
            cateto2.text = cateto2.text! + digit
        }

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.cateto1.delegate = self
        self.cateto2.delegate = self
        self.hipotenuza.delegate = self
        self.grados.delegate = self


       cateto1.inputView = UIView()
       cateto2.inputView = UIView()
    hipotenuza.inputView = UIView ()
        grados.inputView = UIView ()
       cateto1.becomeFirstResponder()
       cateto2.becomeFirstResponder()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al agregar el delegate del UITextField puedes utilizar la siguiente función cuando seleccionas un TextField:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == cateto1 { //Compruebas que textfield hiciste tap.
        cateto1.becomeFirstResponder() //Muestras el teclado.
    }

    if textField == cateto2 {
        cateto2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Y esta función cuando pierdes el foco del TextField:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == cateto1 { //Compruebas que textfield hiciste tap.
        cateto1.resignFirstResponder() // Ocultas el teclado.
    }

    if textField == cateto2 {
        cateto2.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}
```